# Programatically create new media type using fluent API of Umbraco 5.1 

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

Using Umbraco 5.1 API, 
I am able to create a new content type (for creating content nodes under content tab) using the below code.

```
 // create content type
var typeBuilder = context.Hive.Cms().NewContentType("testType", "Test Type")
            .Define("value", "contentPicker", "Content")
            .Commit();

// create content node
var packageNode = context.Hive.Cms().NewRevision(packageNodeName, packageNodeName, "testType");
        packageNode.SetUploadedFile("value", postedFile);            
        packageNode.Publish();
        packageNode.Commit();
```

But is there a way to create media node using fluent API? I need to create a new custom media node with a custom type in the media tab tree. 
I have tried the below approaches, but none of them seem to work

```
1) context.Hive.Cms().NewRevision();
2) context.Hive.Cms<IMediaStore>().NewRevision();
3) builderStep.NewRevision<Media, IMediaStore>();
4) builderStep.NewRevision<TypedEntity, IMediaStore>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but the resulting media type is not complete, as it throws an error "name should be specified" when I try to manually create a media using this type.

```
CmsBuilderStep<IMediaStore> builderStep = new CmsBuilderStep<IMediaStore>(context.Hive);
var typeBuilder = builderStep.NewMediaType<EntitySchema, IMediaStore>("testType")                   
               .Define("package", "uploader", "General Properties")
               .Commit();
```

Finally I decided to create the media type manually, and use the below code to create media item via code

```
        // Creating a new Media item using the scorm package zip file.
        var packageNode = context.Hive.Cms<IContentStore>().NewRevision(packageNodeName, packageNodeName, "testType")
        .SetUploadedFile("package", postedFile)

        // set parent to media root folder - this is what makes it come under media tree
        .SetParent(FixedHiveIds.MediaVirtualRoot)
        .Publish()
        .Commit();
```